# Decimal places after converting from point to raster ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, display, precision

When using "Point to Raster"-Tool in ArcMap I noticed that my point with the elevation of e.g. 128.436m will be converted to a cell with a value of 128.435997.

Is it only a display problem with the identify-tool or was my point be actually edited?

Comment: Explore your point data, what is the precision of the field that the value is coming from? Are you rounding the display for the point dataset and the underlying dataset is at 6 decimal places?

Comment: I created the point-shp from a xyz-file with 3 decimal places. So they should only have 3 decimal places instead of 6 as in the converted raster (shown with the identify-tool).

I also tried to convert the created raster back to ascii-format and I saw again only 3 decimal places in that ascii-file.

Comment: Interesting so if it is 3 decimal places in the ASCII file then it suggests to some sort of display issue.Not sure why?

Comment: IEEE floating-point representation issues would explain why a 4-byte float would round to ...997 on display.

Comment: @Vince: So is it just a display problem?

Comment: More a formatting issue, not specifying a ".3" in the float-text conversion, though a [web calculator](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=049050056046052051054) indicates that  the closest value is 1.28436004638671875e2 (rounding up, not down). But Z values in file geodatabase are stored as compressed integers, so you'd need to take the scalefactor into account as well.

Comment: @Vince: Oh it seems to be really that problem and you are right, I am not only seeing elevation rounding down but also rounding up. The number I wrote on the question was just a quick example, so in that case it should really be 128.436004.

But is there any posibility to have the raster round up to 3 decimal places only?

Comment: Only if you have control of the formatting of the value during display, or if you change the units to thousandths and use 4-byte integer representation.

Comment: Why 1/100 of a millimeter is an issue?